# Make an iframe as light-weight and restricted/secure as possible?

Tags: javascript, iframe

In the context of using a local server only (for desktop), I'm trying to accept user input to allow for HTML/CSS/JS to render their extended notes stored in a local database and displayed using `srcdoc`. The iframe should never be able to load content from any source other than requesting it from the local url.

It's not hard to just get it to work but I'm not sure how to make it as secure as possible and to use as little memory as possible since it is somewhat limited in its functionality. By secure, I mean if one user attempts to use the "shared notes" from another, I wouldn't want those notes to be able to load anything externally.

Thus far, I've used `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-modal"`. Is there anything else that should/could be done?

In terms of memory usage, I looked at web components and, although they are written of in terms of "encapsulating functionality" and sometimes refer to scripts/methods as being private, they don't seem to truly separate the JS code of the component from the parent JS code and don't appear to be flexible in terms of the user frequently changing the content as it is built. But there is also a warning about an iframe potentially using  a lot of resources, such as at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#try_it). Is there anything that can be done to keep that to a minimum when everything is only local and same-origin?

This is all coded in plain JS, no frameworks.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try [allow-same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#allow-same-origin). This can be useful if the ```iframe``` content is from the same domain, but it can also be a security risk if the content is not fully trusted. ```sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"```